# React Dumb component Typescript error: Element is not a constructor function for JSX elements, property 'render' is missing

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
"Dependencies":{
"typescript": "2.6.2"
"@types/react": "15.0.35",
"react": "15.6.1",
}
```

I'm trying to make a 'dumb component' but typescript isn't accepting my function definition.

> (TS) JSX element type '() => Element' is not a constructor function
>   for JSX elements. Property 'render' is missing in type '() =>
>   Element'.

Code its not accepting.

```
const Layout = (props: Invoice) => {
        const noResult = () => <p><em>Nothing found.</em></p>;

        const showResult = () => {
            return (
                <div className="col-sm-10" >
                    <div id="screenshotPlaceholder">
                        <div className="invoice-container">

                            <Header {...props} />

                            <div className="invoice-content">
                                <Content {...props } />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>)
        };

        if (props === null)
            return noResult;
        return showResult;   
    }
```

If I change the last two returns to something like pictured below then it will work, but its less clean.

```
if (props === null)
    return <div>{noResult}</div>;
return <div>{showResult}</div>;
```

It seems it needs a return statement with JSX inline for it to be recognized as a JSX component? Is my component too 'smart' to be made using 'dumb component' syntax? I thought this was rather elegant if it had worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is not an issue with smart & dumb components or react.**

You should call the functions noResult & showResult, For example `noResult` is a function definition. `noResult()` will call the actual function and return `<p><em>Nothing found.</em></p>`

```
const Layout = (props: Invoice) => {
    const noResult = () => <p><em>Nothing found.</em></p>;

    const showResult = () => {
        return (
            <div className="col-sm-10" >
                <div id="screenshotPlaceholder">
                    <div className="invoice-container">

                        <Header {...props} />

                        <div className="invoice-content">
                            <Content {...props } />
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>)
    };

    if (props === null)
        return noResult(); // ****** Note here
    return showResult();  // ****** And here
}
```

Comment: Using functions works! Thanks I will accept this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the extra functions wrapping:

```
const Layout = (props: Invoice) => {
  const noResult = (
    <p>
      <em>Nothing found.</em>
    </p>
  );

  const showResult = (
    <div className="col-sm-10">
      <div id="screenshotPlaceholder">
        <div className="invoice-container">
          <Header {...props} />

          <div className="invoice-content">
            <Content {...props} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

  if (props === null)
    return noResult;
  return showResult;
};
```

Or you can leave the definitions alone and call the functions instead:

```
  const noResult = () => <p><em>Nothing found.</em></p>;
  const showResult = () => {
  // ...
  };

  if (props === null)
    return noResult();
  return showResult();
```